# Finding SUM, AVG, and DIFF of columns using Python with a CSV

Tags: python, csv, average, difference

Working with a CSV on Python 3.8 that goes something like:

> 

- **Column_0**>>>>>>>>>**Column_1**>>>>>>**Column_2**>>>>**Column_3**>>>>>**Column_4**
- *Some_Numbers0*>>>*Some_String1*>>>*Some_String2*>*Some_Numbers3*>>Some_Numbers4

Now, the numbers in Column_3 and Column_4 are what need to be SUM, AVG, and finding the differences of their totals.

I'm currently stuck on trying to get **both sums to print**. This is how far i've got:

```
import csv
import decimal

with open("sample.csv") as myFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(myFile)
    print(sum(float(line["Column_3"]) for line in reader))
    print(sum(float(line["Column_4"]) for line in reader))
```

Using this, Column_3's total prints but Column_4 I get a "0". Remove prin line for Column_3, then I get Column_4's total just fine. I've also tried:

```
import csv
import decimal

with open("sample.csv") as myFile:
    total = 0
    for line in csv.DictReader(myFile):
        total += int(line["Column_3"])
    print(total)
```

> ```
> but i get
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "some file pathway", line 7, in <module>
>     total += int(line["Column_3"])
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1345.67'
> ```

Which that number represents the first number value of that column_3.

I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated. I'm sure I'll be returning with questions on finding the AVG and then using their totals to find their differences, all need to print running from the same program but here I am already stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your reader object can only go through the CSV file once, because you go through the list with col 3 its wont print for col 4 because there's nothing left to read. Your second approach would be fine, just replace int() with float() because your working with decimals